# Performance of static library with base SDK 6.1 on application with base SDK 7

Tags: ios, ios7, static-libraries

I read some articles for SDK 7, and [64-bit Transition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) guide for performance but I didn't get clear idea so guys I need your help, thanks in advance.

I have static library with base SDK 6.1[Xcode 4.6], which is not optimized for base SDK 7 and 64-bit, so my queries are like,

1) Is this fine to use static library with SDK 6.1 for application with base SDK 7, will there be any issue?

2) Will applications built on 64-Bit links properly with library built on 32-Bit library?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the 64 bit transition guide to understand what this means. Your question is too general and no one can tell you if your particular library will work properly in a 64 bit environment or not.

Data types and pointer sizes are different in 64 bit, vs the 32 bit version of iOS. So it really depends on what your static library is doing.

Building and linking may not be a problem for your static library. The problems may occur when your run your app because calculations could produce different results than what you expected. Additionally, if your app interacts with 32 bit versions, then there could be problems because the data types are of different sizes.

Comment: thank for your reply, I have read about 64-Bit transition as mentioned in question , but I was not clear about performance of static library built on SDK 6 on application built on SDK7.

Comment: the performance will depend on a number of things. Again no one can answer your question so easily